# How to dynamically print next page info from restAPI in Angular 13

Tags: angular

This is my **page.ts**

```
export class CharactersPage {
  url: string = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=1";
  chars: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getInfo();
  }

 async getInfo() {
    this.http.get<any>(this.url).subscribe(res => {
      this.chars = res.results
    });
  }

}
```

This is my **page.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let chars of chars | filter:searchTerm" id="item">
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <ion-img src="{{ chars.image }}"></ion-img>
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <ion-label>{{ chars.name }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

What i get using this code is the first 20 characters.
I want to be able to print all the characters without having to make a different request everytime.
The are in total 42 pages with 20 characters on each(except the 42th which only has 6).
I tried using while loop but angular keeps crashing on me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try joining (combine) the requests into one using rxjs [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest).

So do something like a `"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=pageId"` and iterate the pages you want then combine the observables into one.

```
const url ='https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=';
const pages = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
const observables = pages.map(pageId => this.http.get<any>(this.url+pageId));

combineLatest(observables).pipe(map(values) => ({...values})).subscribe(res => {
      this.chars = res.results
});
```

**Note** this will still result in multiple requests. If you want a single request the api must be able to handle it.

Also, the function `getInfo` is not async

Comment: I think `res.results` must be called in each one of `values`, not on the combined `res`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on ducumentation https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#info-and-pagination the api supports some kind of pagination and you will have to implement custom one. Making 42 sequential request its not an option to my opinion.

You can check these two links with prev/next buttons implementation:

[rick and morty pagination](https://codepen.io/codedbyEmre/pen/KKVvrQE)

```
.
```

[react rick and morty pagination](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/pagination-with-the-rick-and-morty-api-1e136be0f225)

Answer (score 0):

Like others have already pointed out, if the API does not support getting more than 20 items per request, you would need to implement some kind of recursive HTTP calls to retrieve all items "at once". That in general is bad practice (not good for the server and the client) and you should instead implement some kind of pagination.

Nevertheless, here is an example of how you could to it recursively:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  chars = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    void this.getAllChars();
  }

  async getAllChars() {
    let url = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=1';
    let res;

    do {
      res = await this.http.get(url).toPromise();
      this.chars = [...this.chars, ...res.results];
      url = res.info.next;
    } while (res.info.next);
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked thx, do you know how i can add pagination? i want to add a list style where you click "see more" and more character would show up.

Comment: @BenchmarkMaster You asked for an answer of how to do this WITHOUT pagination, you want all data at once instead, but now you are asking for pagination in comment?

Comment: @BenchmarkMaster as a first simple step, you should only display a fixed number of characters at a time (e.g. 20) and implement a "Prev" and "Next" button. When for example clicking on "Next", make a request to the API with `currentPage + 1` and display the results in your view.